# Angular Material Table doesnt show sorted table

Tags: angular, mat-table

earthlings!
I am desperately trying to get sorting to work on my mat table. At first I thought that it didn't work at all, however
using

```
<table mat-table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" [dataSource]="source" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

and

```js
sortData(event: any){
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   console.log(this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.data, this.sort));
   this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor
}
```

I am able to determine that sorting works (via console log), however my table displayed stays the same

[image]

Background: I am using a json server npm package and displaying the data (from subscription) in a mat-table. I am quite positive it has something to do with the subscription of the data (it not being avilable outright). However there are no data refreshes happening (logging refreshes as well):

```js
loadData() {
    this.dataService.getAllData().subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.data = response;
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IData>(this.data);
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
     console.log('getting Data');
   });
}
```

I'm not sure how would I go about setting up a stackblitz for such a scenario.

I have knocked down some usual suspects - MatSortModule is imported in app module, MatColumnDef"xxx" matches data column name "xxx".

Any help would be great or if there are some other code snippets i could show.

Comment: `matSortChange` So this event occurs, at that time You want to change data ?

Comment: no, this event occurs when I click on  header to sort data. I want the table rows to reorder to conform with the output in the console log pictured

Comment: Hmm. WEll I can see that the example works. The only difference that I can see is that it's getting the data via @Input() and not directly from component. I have even now added matSortDirection and matSortActive to the <table> out of desperation. But the sorting just  is not connected to my DOM (see imgur link in the other post for comparison between console and dom)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gseuop? yep, I created this. But ofcourse it's working in stackblitz....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240331/discussion-between-grd-and-shredder).

Answer (score 2):

when you use a MatTableDataSource(*) with sort you:

1.-use ViewChild to get the "sort"

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

2.-assing the sort **after** create the dataSource and when the table is visible.

```
 this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(data)
 this.dataSource.sort=this.sort
```

The second condition means that, if we are using a service to get the data we need equal inside subscribe

```
 this.myService.getData().subscribe((res:any)=>{
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(res)
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort
 }
```

BUT also means that if we has in .html some like

```
  <div *ngIf="dataSource" else loading>
     <table mat-table>...</table>
  </div>
  <ng-template #loading>
    loading...
  </ng-template>
```

We need Angular give a change to display the data (usign a setTimeout), and after assing the sort

```
 this.myService.getData().subscribe((res:any)=>{
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(res)
    seTimeout(()=>{
       this.dataSource.sort=this.sort
    })
 }
```

(*)And what about you don't use a MatTableDataSource?, remember that a dataSource can be a MatTableDataSource or an Array (or and observable with pipe async). in this case (and only in this case) is when we use the event `(matSortChange)`. Well, also, if we want use a custom sort we use the event.

In this case we change directly the datasource (the array)

Answer (score 0):

Set initially as an empty array in property declaration

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IData>([]);
```

Now you will never reset dataSource by `new MatTableDataSource`. Only use its `dataSource.data` property to set it up.

```
loadData() {
    this.dataService.getAllData().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data = response;
      this.dataSource.data = this.data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had not tried the <any>-way. However it has not worked (or my this.sort is set up incorrect. Anyway, this happens (or should I say, doesnt happen) when i click on a column to sort it a few times: https://i.imgur.com/8og5yCs.png

Comment: you can put any type you want <any> was just an example

Comment: you are replying very vaguely, i can not understand by console log what exactly is not working, where is the problem at

Comment: From the imagr you can see that the IDsfor example are ordered differently on the left and on the right side. It shouldn't happen