# MatSort in angular material is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I tried the tutorial of mat sort in Material Angular, but when I apply it to my end it is not working. I tried to get my list data in web api, but when the data is static the `matSort` is working how to achieve that?

I got error `ERROR TypeError: data.map is not a function`

```
 <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="Item" matSort>
                
                  
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="Item">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Item No </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Items}}</mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="Item2">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Item Name </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Item1}}</mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  
                  

              <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
              </mat-table>
              <mat-paginator  [length]="ItemObject?.count"
                          [pageSizeOptions]="[50]"
                          (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)"
                          showFirstLastButtons>
              </mat-paginator>
```

TS

```
Item: MatTableDataSource<ItemDTO>;

constructor(private ItemService: ItemService) { }

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

getList(){
    this.ItemService.getItem(50, 1, true).pipe(first()).subscribe((response: ItemDTO) => {
      this.Item = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      this.Item.sort = this.sort
    })
  }
```

Services

```
    getItem(size: number, index: number,isActive:boolean){
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('Size', String(size));
        params = params.append('Index', String(index));
        params = params.append('isActive', String(isActive));
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'Item/list', {params}).pipe(map(data => data.map(o => this.toList(o))));
      }


private toList(obj: any):Item[]{
    console.log(obj);
    return {
    Items:obj.Items,
    Item1:obj.Item1
    }
  }


"items": [
    {
      items:test
      "itemDetails": {
      item1:test
      }
    },
```

Comment: See that if the data you recived is null (or is not an array) you can not make a "map". Futhermore, In strict mode you should indicate Angular that it's an array:`map((data:any[]) => data.map(o => this.toList(o))))`. BTW, your function toList return an Object (with two properties Items and Item1) and you're saying Angular that return `Item[]`

Comment: @Eliseo i update my question i add the data that i received

Comment: You receive an object with a property:items", is in this property where you has the array, so you should use `this.http.get<Object[]>(...).pipe(map((data:any) => data.items.map(o => this.toList(o))));` -see that you use `data.items`-

Comment: @Eliseo the error is now gone but the sort is not working 

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sort')`

Comment: Are you mat-table under a "*ngIf"? if true, remove the `{static:true}` and take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446068/angular-material-table-doesnt-show-sorted-table/70471788#70471788)

Comment: i resolve it with my naming for matColumnDef anyways thank you @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

MatSort can be tricky, especially when the table is within an *ngIf.

My personal best practice is a setter for the MatSort. Try this:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true})
  set matSort(sort: MatSort) {
    this.Item.sort = sort;
  }
```

With this, remove the line `this.Item.sort = this.sort;` in your subscription callback.

Comment: Should be `{static:false}` (you can also remove it). static:true makes that only check the element for first time, a [stackblictz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kmzk8r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for demo

Comment: still got error  `return this.http.get<Object[]>(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'Item/list', {params}).pipe(map(data => data.map(o => this.toList(o))));`